# Spring Security ACL: I cannot update ACL (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I am trying to learn and apply to my Spring Boot project some Spring Security ACL controls. Thus I have tried to reuse the code snippet from [Spring Security reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#domain-acls-getting-started), which I have adapted a little bit to my project needs.

I have the following component to populate the database with some initial values at start time.

```
@Component
public class AppBootstrap {

    private Authority adminAuth;
    private User admin;
    private TimeSheet timeSheetAdmin;

    private final JdbcMutableAclService jdbcMutableAclService;

    private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    public AppBootstrap(JdbcMutableAclService jdbcMutableAclService, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.jdbcMutableAclService = jdbcMutableAclService;
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner initialAuthorities(AuthorityRepository authorityRepository) {
        return args -> {
            adminAuth = new Authority(ROLE_ADMIN);
            authorityRepository.save(adminAuth);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner initialUsers(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return args -> {
            admin = new User("admin",
                    "{bcrypt}$2a$08$lDnHPz7eUkSi6ao14Twuau08mzhWrL4kyZGGU5xfiGALO/Vxd5DOi", "admin",
                    "admin", "admin@example.com", true, getDate(2016, JANUARY, 1));
            admin.setAuthorities(asList(adminAuth));

            userRepository.save(admin);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner initialTimeSheets(TimeSheetRepository timeSheetRepository) {
        return args -> {
            timeSheetAdmin = new TimeSheet(LocalDate.of(2016, MARCH, 1), admin);

            timeSheetRepository.save(timeSheetUser);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner initialRights() {
        return args -> grantPermission(admin, timeSheetAdmin, ADMINISTRATION);
    }

    MutableAcl grantPermission(User user, TimeSheet timeSheet, Permission p) {
        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        var authorities = user.getAuthorities().stream().map(auth -> auth.getName().toString()).collect(toList());
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPass(), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(authorities.toArray(new String[]{})));
        securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

        ObjectIdentity oiTimeSheet = new ObjectIdentityImpl(TimeSheet.class, timeSheet.getId());

        Sid sidAdmin = new PrincipalSid(user.getUsername());

        MutableAcl acl;
        try {
            acl = (MutableAcl) jdbcMutableAclService.readAclById(oiTimeSheet);
        } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
            acl = transactionTemplate.execute(status -> jdbcMutableAclService.createAcl(oiTimeSheet));
        }

        acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), p, sidAdmin, true);

        // updating permission
        MutableAcl finalAcl = acl;
        return transactionTemplate.execute(status -> jdbcMutableAclService.updateAcl(finalAcl));
    }
}
```

This method is ran every time the application context is refreshed. I can see that, if I run just one test method (or test class), it runs successfully. These tests are end to end tests (`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) @SpringBootTest`). Also, no problem to run my `@SpringBootApplication` alone. But if I run all tests at once, almost all `@SpringBootTest` are failing with the following stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:781)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into acl_entry (acl_object_identity, ace_order, sid, mask, granting, audit_success, audit_failure)values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`iresource2test`.`acl_entry`, CONSTRAINT `fk_acl_entry_object` FOREIGN KEY (`acl_object_identity`) REFERENCES `acl_object_identity` (`id`)); nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`iresource2test`.`acl_entry`, CONSTRAINT `fk_acl_entry_object` FOREIGN KEY (`acl_object_identity`) REFERENCES `acl_object_identity` (`id`))
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:246)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:634)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:924)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService.createEntries(JdbcMutableAclService.java:138)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService.updateAcl(JdbcMutableAclService.java:363)
    at com.roberto.bootstrap.AppBootstrap.lambda$grantPermission$6(AppBootstrap.java:144)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at com.roberto.bootstrap.AppBootstrap.grantPermission(AppBootstrap.java:144)
    at com.roberto.bootstrap.AppBootstrap.lambda$initialRights$3(AppBootstrap.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`iresource2test`.`acl_entry`, CONSTRAINT `fk_acl_entry_object` FOREIGN KEY (`acl_object_identity`) REFERENCES `acl_object_identity` (`id`))
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:210)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:185)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:192)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:218)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(ClientPreparedStatement.java:864)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:839)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:128)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$batchUpdate$2(JdbcTemplate.java:938)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`iresource2test`.`acl_entry`, CONSTRAINT `fk_acl_entry_object` FOREIGN KEY (`acl_object_identity`) REFERENCES `acl_object_identity` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(ClientPreparedStatement.java:843)
    ... 52 more
```

I have a couple of questions:

- Why this error happens when I run more than one test class?
- How can I find a workaround? Is there a better way to accomplish the same?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question did not become so popular, I tried a different approach which seems to work great :-)

First I created a new ACLService class, to isolate all interactions with JdbcMutableAclService.

```
package com.roberto.security.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.acls.model.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 * Service class to handle ACL permissions.
 */
@Service
public class ACLService {
    private final MutableAclService mutableAclService;

    @Autowired
    public ACLService(MutableAclService mutableAclService) {
        this.mutableAclService = mutableAclService;
    }

    /**
     * Insert an ACL entry
     * @param oid represents the model object
     * @param recipient represents the principal (user, group of users, etc)
     * @param permission quite explicit name...
     * @return the new ACL database entry
     */
    public MutableAcl addPermission(ObjectIdentity oid, Sid recipient, Permission permission) {
        MutableAcl acl;

        try {
            acl = (MutableAcl) mutableAclService.readAclById(oid);
        } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
            acl = mutableAclService.createAcl(oid);
        }

        acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), permission, recipient, true);
        return mutableAclService.updateAcl(acl);
    }   
}
```

Then I created another integration test which runs properly, without the IllegalStateException. Now I will just have to call it from my bootstrap class.

```
package com.roberto.security.service;

import com.roberto.model.TimeSheet;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission;
import org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl;
import org.springframework.security.acls.domain.PrincipalSid;
import org.springframework.security.acls.model.*;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD;

/**
 * This test handles basic interaction between our codebase
 * Spring Security ACL and the underlying database model
 */
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ACLServiceIntegrationTest {

    private Authentication authentication;
    private ObjectIdentity oid ;
    private Sid sid;
    private Permission administration = BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION;

    @Autowired
    private ACLService aclService;

    @Autowired
    private MutableAclService mutableAclService;

    @Autowired
    private PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        authentication = TestSecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        sid = new PrincipalSid(((JwtUser) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
        oid = new ObjectIdentityImpl(TimeSheet.class, 1);
    }

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("admin")
    public void testBeans() {
        assertNotNull(aclService);
        assertNotNull(mutableAclService);
        assertNotNull(permissionEvaluator);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @WithUserDetails("admin")
    @DirtiesContext(methodMode = AFTER_METHOD)
    public void addPermissionIntegrationTest() {
        assertFalse(permissionEvaluator.hasPermission(authentication, oid.getIdentifier(), oid.getType(), administration));

        MutableAcl acl = aclService.addPermission(oi, sid, administration);

        assertTrue(permissionEvaluator.hasPermission(authentication, oid.getIdentifier(), oid.getType(), administration));

        assertEquals(TimeSheet.class.toString().split(" ")[1], acl.getObjectIdentity().getType());
        assertTrue(acl.getEntries().stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getSid().equals(sid) && e.getPermission().equals(administration)));
        assertTrue(acl.isGranted(List.of(administration), List.of(sid), true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
In my case the acl cache was dirty. I had to clear the cache after each test, then all tests run green, even if called together.
I created a TestExcutionListener for that. Just annotate your  abstract Test class with it:

```
@TestExecutionListeners(
    value = ClearAclCacheTestExecutionListener.class,
    mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS) 
public class AbstractTest{...}
```

```
public class ClearAclCacheTestExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    private AclCache aclCache;

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) {
        testContext.getApplicationContext()
                .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
                .autowireBean(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        super.afterTestMethod(testContext);
        aclCache.clearCache();
    }
}
```